# Mock HttpHeaders throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, mockito

I am new for Mockito and I mock HttpHeaders in my TestClass but it is throwing NullPointerException if I removes setUp() method and mocked HttpHeaders and i don't want to write all that code in my setup() methods and i just want to mocked HttpHeaders. Can someone suggest me how to solve this issue

### Test class

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class ValidateAndQuotetValidatorTest {

        @InjectMocks
        private ValidateAndQuotetValidator validator;

        @Mock
        private HttpHeaders headers;

   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        List<String> requestHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> requestHeaders = new MultivaluedHashMap<> ();
        headers = new HttpHeaders() {

            @Override
            public MultivaluedMap<String, String> getRequestHeaders() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return requestHeaders;
            }

            @Override
            public List<String> getRequestHeader(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return requestHeader;
            }

            @Override
            public MediaType getMediaType() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getLength() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Locale getLanguage() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getHeaderString(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Date getDate() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, Cookie> getCookies() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public List<MediaType> getAcceptableMediaTypes() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public List<Locale> getAcceptableLanguages() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
    }


        @Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
        public void test_validateRequest_12() throws Exception {
            headers.getRequestHeaders().putSingle(ExternalPartnerUtil.PARTNER_NAME, "");
            headers.getRequestHeaders().putSingle(ExternalPartnerUtil.AGENT_ID, "asd");
            validator.validateHeaders(headers);
        }
    }
```

### Exception

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.sampl.demo.exception.ServiceException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
```

Comment: Please share your entire test class

Comment: I updated my code with my problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

The first probable mistake is not using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` runner.

Take a look here for examples:
https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-unit-testing-and-mocking-with-mockito-and-junit

The second one is that inside validator some method can be called on result of headers method invocation. In that case you need to use `when()` method. For instance:

```
when(headers.getHeader("accept")).thenReturn("application/json");
```

Comment: @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  Mockito.when(headers.getHeaderString("accept")).thenReturn("application/json");
 }

Comment: @Krish you should not reinitialized headers in setup method. Remove this lines of code `headers = new HttpHeaders()`

Comment: @Krish Does ValidateAndQuotetValidator has a field of HttpHeaders?